# Find all the numbers such that "Sum of cube of digits=Number itself"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, palindrome

I want to find all the numbers such that "Sum of cube of digits=Number itself".

For example, I am seeking for numbers like $153$ as $1^3+5^3+3^3=153$

I know by hit and trial that there are 6 such numbers ( $0,1,153,370,371,407$), But I need it in a pure mathematical way.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: $153, 370, 371, 407$.  See, e.g., [Narcissistic Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NarcissisticNumber.html)

Comment: Man I said I know only six numbers are there those are 0,1,153,370,407,,, But I did it with the help of a program  .How to do it mathematically???

Comment: To be clear:  this is just a finite problem.  If $f(n)$ denotes the sum of the cubes of the digits of $n$  then obviously $f(n)≤729\times L(n)$ where $L(n)$ is the number of digits in $n$.  But $L(n)=\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil$ so...

Comment: Not following you.  Those numbers do not appear anywhere in your post.

Comment: So what ,, I didn't understood please be clear...!  Sorry for the language I used

Comment: Question is how did you find them

Comment: For Heavens' sakes.  You can get a bound on $n$ since $n$ grows a lot faster than $729\times \log_{10}n$.  Then all you have to do is to check that finite list.  To be precise:  at around $x=2473$ we have $x=729\times \log_{10}x$, below that is a numerical accident..best checked case by case.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031334/please-verify-my-proof-of-there-is-no-integer-geq2-sum-of-squares-of-whose-d

Comment: Downvoted due to unrelenting ungracious comments on own OP.

Comment: Sorry @Bacon, will you please clarify comment to me. I can't get it

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. It seems to me that the OP was irritated at the very useful comments (s)he was given by you and others. I gave you a +1 for continuing to help, I downvoted the OP for begin ungracious.

Comment: Well, I got it now. :) :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me show you what I have done:

Suppose such a number exist (sum cube of digits=number itself), then it will be of the form (as usual):
$$10^{n-1}a_0+10^{n-2}a_1+.........10a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}={a_0}^3+{a_1}^3+.......{a_{n-2}}^3+{a_{n-1}}^3$$
Which on further solving becomes,
$$a_0(10^{n-1}-a_0{^2})+a_1(10^{n-2}-a_1{^2})+.........+a_{n-2}(10-a_{n-2}{^2})+a_{n-1}(1-a_{n-1}{^2})=0$$
$$a_0(10^{n-1}-a_0{^2})+a_1(10^{n-2}-a_1{^2})+.........+a_{n-2}(10-a_{n-2}{^2})=a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}{^2}-1)$$

Now, the hardest part comes:

The terms of left are all positive and they increase as we keep on going towards left.

We can only compare the terms $$a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}{^2}-1)$$ and $$a_{n-2}(10-a_{n-2}{^2})+a_{n-3}(100-a_{n-3}^2)$$ because the shortest of other terms is too far from comparison.

Now if we make some comparison, we will have $$a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}{^2}-1)=a_{n-2}(10-a_{n-2}{^2})+(a_{n-3})(100-a_{n-3}{^2})$$

Now let's form a table for the separated functions:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
a_{n-2}&            a_{n-2}(10-a_{n-2}{^2})\\\hline
0&                          0\\
1&                          9\\
2&                          12\\
3&                           3\\
4&                         -24\\                         
5&                         -75\\
6&                         -156\\
7&                         -273\\
8&                         -592\\
9&                         -639
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
a_{n-1}&                       a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}^{2}-1)\\\hline
0&                                  0\\
1&                                  0\\
2&                                  6\\
3&                                  24\\
4&                                 60\\
5&                                 120\\
6&                                 210\\
7&                                 336\\
8&                                 504\\
9&                                 720
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
a_{n-3}&                       a_{n-3}(100-a_{n-3}^{2})\\\hline
0&                                  0\\
1&                                  99\\
2&                                 192\\
3&                                  273\\
4&                                 336\\
5&                                 375\\
6&                                 384\\
7&                                 357\\
8&                                 288\\
9&                                 171
\end{array}$$

Now just look at the tables and find the numbers ($a_{n-1},a_{n-2},a_{n-3}$) which follow the following condition:

$$a_{n-3}(100-a_{n-3}{^2})+a_{n-2}(10-a_{n-2}{^2})=a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}{^2}-1)$$

A quick look at the table will give you following set of values of ($a_{n-3},a_{n-2},a_{n-1}$.

$1. 000$ or $0$

$2.001$ or $1$

$3.153$

$   4.370 $

$   5.371$

$    6.407$

Comment: This is a lot of work! (+1).  I am standing by my claim that simply checking the numbers up to $2473$ is the way to go.

Comment: Yes I know @lulu, As you claimed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031334/please-verify-my-proof-of-there-is-no-integer-geq2-sum-of-squares-of-whose-d). But showing own work gives the greatest feeling.

Comment: I liked your work @lone wolf  And now I am able to understand what you were saying lulu  ,,,, sorry for the quarrel

Comment: No argument from me!  Nothing better than digging into the details.